# Optimize nested array from path strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given this simple array of objects:

```
var allPaths = [
  {path: "/", component: 'cmp-1'},
  {path: "/my-cool-list/", component: 'cmp-2'},
  {path: "/my-cool-list/this-is-card-1", component: 'cmp-3'},
  {path: "/my-cool-list/this-is-card-2", component: 'cmp-4'},
  {path: "/blog/", component: 'cmp-5'},
  {path: "/blog/2017/01/this-is-card-3", component: 'cmp-6'},
  {path: "/blog/2017/02/this-is-card-4", component: 'cmp-7'},
  {path: "/recettes/", component: 'cmp-8'},
  {path: "/recettes/this-is-card-5", component: 'cmp-9'},
  {path: "/recettes/this-is-card-6", component: 'cmp-10'}
]
```

In need to produce this output:

```
[
  {
    path: "/", component: 'cmp-1'
  },
  {
    path: "/my-cool-list",
    component: 'cmp-2',
    children: [
      {path: "/this-is-card-1", component: 'cmp-3'},
      {path: "/this-is-card-2", component: 'cmp-4'}
    ]
  },

  {
    path: "/blog",
    component: 'cmp-5',
    children: [
      {
        path: "/2017",
        children: [
          {
            path: "/01",
            children: [
              {path: "/this-is-card-3", component: 'cmp-6'}
            ]
          },
          {
            path: "/02",
            children: [
              {path: "/this-is-card-4", component: 'cmp-7'}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    path: "/recettes",
    component: 'cmp-8',
    children: [
      {path: "/this-is-card-5", component: 'cmp-9'},
      {path: "/this-is-card-6", component: 'cmp-10'}
    ]
  },
]
```

One way I found to do this is by:

1. traverse each object in `allPaths`
2. create a valid output for each paths (like if only this path was provided)
3. push resulting object into an array named `tree`
4. ...rinse and repeat...
5. then deeply merge resulting `tree` into a unique one.

The code look something like this [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/od3sfqs0/7/):

```
let tree = []

// Recursive Tree Builder
const buildTree = (pathArray, ...others) => {
    var currentToken = pathArray.shift()
    var arr = []
    if (pathArray.length>0) {
       arr.push( {path: '/'+currentToken, children: []} )
       arr[0].children = buildTree(pathArray, ...others)
    } else {
       arr.push( Object.assign( {path: '/'+currentToken}, others[0] ))
    }
    return arr;  
}

// For each object in `allPaths`, build a tree
allPaths.map( page => {
   let {path, ...rest} = page    
   let res = buildTree(path.split('/').slice(1), rest)
   tree.push(res[0])
})

// external code to deeply merge each objects in `tree` (external library: no need to put the code here but you got the point)
```

I guess there should be a way to construct the final output lazily, without requiring yet another merge operation at the end: like constructing the final tree on the go without intermediate storing + another operation.

To narrow down the question further, I attempted to build the tree on-the-fly but I got stuck while attempting to push an entry to precise location in the tree. For example, keeping reference to `tree[0].children[0].children[0].children[0] ...` bugs me as I don't know how deeper I'll find the related path or if `children` will even exist at this level.

A pseudo code (I imagine), would be :

1. traverse `allPaths` objects one by one

*(pretend the first object traversed has path like `/blog/level-2`)*

2. search the `tree` for the 1st level found in `path` (ex: `/blog` in `/blog/level-2`)
3. not found ? then, push object in the tree
4. this path has further levels (like in `/blog/level-2`) ?
5. .......yes ? go one level deeper (`/level-2`) into `children` and repeat from step 3
6. .......no  ? reset level to 0. break

Now I have difficulties to achieve those ***levels*** tracking as:
- I don't know how to easily query the `tree` given a path: `/blog/level-2` may be at `tree[2].children[14]` or `tree[32].children[57]` and I have hard time to query it but moreover to STORE this info for later use.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: it seems it is angular2 router definition. Why don't you just manually write the file instead of creating a function

Comment: No sorry, it has nothing to do with Angular. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out myself.

```
const appendToTree = (tree, obj) => {
  // extract path from object
  let {path, ...rest} = obj

  // turn path into array of params
  let URLparams = path.split('/').slice(1)

  // recursive calls could send empty array
  if (URLparams.length === 0) return tree

  // take out first element in array: removes it from the array as well
  let currentURLparam = URLparams.shift()
  // reset path to what's left in URLparams after shift
    path = '/' + URLparams.join('/')

  let currentPosition = 0, 
      currentNode = {},
      found = false

loopTree:  // find corresponding param in tree
  for(currentPosition; currentPosition < tree.length; currentPosition++) {
    if (tree[currentPosition].path === '/'+currentURLparam) {
       currentNode = tree[currentPosition]
       found = true
       break loopTree
    }
  }

  if(  found ) {  // found a matching path
    // get a reference to children or create an empty one
    currentNode['children'] = currentNode.children || []
    // repeat all, but with current reference and val which has been shifted before
    return appendToTree(currentNode.children, {path, ...rest})
  } else {  // not matching path found: insert it
    if (URLparams.length > 0) {  // still have URL params left ?
       // push current page object into array
       // Here we could force any default props to index levels
       let pos = tree.push({path: '/'+currentURLparam, children: []}) - 1
       // we still have params to process, so we proceed another iteration
       return appendToTree(tree[pos].children, {path, ...rest})
    } else { // no URL params left, this is the last one in stack
       tree.push({path: '/'+currentURLparam, ...rest})
       return tree
    }
  }
}



const buildTree = (tree, pages) => {
  // Traverse all pages objects and append each to provided tree
  pages.map(page => {
    appendToTree(tree, page)
  })
  return tree
}
```

Then, we just need to call:

```
buildTree([], allPaths)
```

...it will correctly create a tree on the fly, as we traverse each object in `allPaths`.
To solve my problem, I used recursion.